# DRF SimpleJWT Custom claims not getting updated on token refresh

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've followed the docs to implement simple jwt, but I'm facing an issue. When I PATCH a user, and then try to refresh this user's token, the claims inside the token are outdated. The only way I can get the new claims is to logout and create a new token.

This is my custom serializer:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['email'] = user.email
        token['name'] = user.name
        token['birthday'] = user.birthday.isoformat()
        token['reading_goal_minutes'] = user.reading_goal_minutes
        return token
```

Custom view:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Urls:

```
path('token/', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
```

Settings:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import timedelta
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.UserData'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'corsheaders',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=90),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": True,

    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "VERIFYING_KEY": "",
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JSON_ENCODER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,

    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",

    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",

    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",

    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),

    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.MyTokenObtainPairSerializer",
    "TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSerializer",
    "TOKEN_VERIFY_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenVerifySerializer",
    "TOKEN_BLACKLIST_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenBlacklistSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenObtainSlidingSerializer",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.TokenRefreshSlidingSerializer",
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'umoy.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'webapp/build'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'umoy.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DJANGO_DB_PORT'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'webapp/build/static'
]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```